# XPM Update Preview not working with LDAP

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager, updatepreview

We have configured CMS with LDAP authentication and also have XPM enabled. When user is trying to perform "Update Preview" he is getting error "Invalid URI : tcm:0-0-0.”

While looking into CMS event viewer I am getting below error, please let me know what could be the issue?

```
Invalid URI: tcm:0-0-0.
Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService Errorcode: 805 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
StackTrace Information Details:
    at Tridion.ContentManager.Utilities.AssertUriNotNull(TcmUri uri, Boolean failOnUriNull)
    at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.AssertValidUris(IEnumerable`1 items)
    at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.ResolveItems(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, PublicationTarget publicationTarget)
    at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
    at SyncInvokePreview(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is related to your LDAP configuration? What happens if you preview the page in the CME?

Comment: I am not sure if there is any LDAP configuration require but just FYI in case some additional settings require for XPM to work with LDAP. We are using SDL RI 1.0.1, where all the content is getting saved into broker database.